# How to query same col1,col2,col3 as rank 1

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 4 columns looks like this

```
Timestamp                | Last Name         | Middle name   | First Name| CSP
2018-01-25 09:20:55.000    Santos              Enriquez        Marco      1
2018-01-25 09:20:55.000    Santos              Enriquez        Marco      1
2018-01-25 09:20:55.000    Ordiz Jr.           Bucoladlan      Nulf       1
2018-01-25 09:20:55.000    Urbiztondo          Aguillion       Bernardo   2
```

What I want to do is. Rank them based on their `Last Name,Middle Name,First Name`

Expected output

```
Rank                    | Last Name         | Middle name         | First Name|
1                         Santos              Enriquez              Marco
1                         Santos              Enriquez              Marco
2                         Ordiz Jr.           Bucoladlan            Nulf
1                         Urbiztondo          Aguillion             Bernardo
```

I Tried using Rank() but it

```
SELECT RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY [Last Name],[Middle Name],[First Name] ORDER BY [Last Name]) RN,
      [Last Name],
      [Middle Name],
      [First Name]
  FROM [IROAv2].[dbo].[AgentMainTbl]
  WHERE [First Name] != 'Arnulfo'
  ORDER BY [Last Name]
```

But I know its wrong it just return `1` for all the rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `dense_rank` and just `order by`:

```
SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY [Last Name], [Middle Name], [First Name]) RN,
      [Last Name], [Middle Name],[First Name]
FROM [IROAv2].[dbo].[AgentMainTbl]
WHERE [First Name] <> 'Arnulfo'
ORDER BY [Last Name];
```

`PARTITION BY` restarts the numbering with every new value of the partition by keys.  You seem to want continuous numbering over the entire table, with triples of the same keys having the same number.

Comment: This is correct but before accepting this answer. Please see my edited post cause I never thought that this column will also effect the sorting.